# Геолокация Андроид

Tags: android, google-play, геолокация, gps

Здравствуйте, подскажите куда копать какие классы мне нужны.

Возможно в фоновом режим отслеживать место нахождение устройства?
И чем отслеживать плей сервисами или LocationListener, но я пробовал без сервисов и он даже с интернетом не может найти место, а плей сервисы отслеживают отлично но не у всех есть(или как то это комбинировать?,или лучше определится с этим чтобы не жрала батарейку?) 
И можно в фоновом режим записывать в базу данных координаты, а при соединении с интернетом он их выгружал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для определения местоположения используется интерфейс [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)
 и класс [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html). Сначала нужно создать объект-слушатель, в котором реализуется интерфейс LocationListener:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //вызывается при обновлении данных о местоположении
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
    //вызывается при изменении статуса указанного провайдера
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    //вызывается при включении указанного провайдера
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    //вызывается при выключении указанного провайдера
    }
};
```

Затем, чтобы слушатель получал данные о местоположении, необходимо запросить их у системы следующим образом:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
```

provider - один из провайдеров местоположения. Основных провайдера два: LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER и LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER. Список доступных провайдеров можно получить с помощью функции:

```
List<String> providersList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
```

minTime - промежуток времени в миллисекундах, через который должны приходить обновления местоположения.

minDistance - минимальное расстояние, через которое обновляется местоположение.

locationListener - наш слушатель местоположения.

Для работы приложения необходимо определить в манифесте следующие разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Проверить наличие этих разрешений во время выполнения программы можно следующим образом:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //у приложения нет разрешений на определение местоположения
    return;
}
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
```

Чтобы отслеживать местоположение в фоновом режиме, используются службы (класс Service). С помощью службы можно записывать данные в файлы, а при наличии интернет-соединения выгружать их на сервер. Проверка наличия интернета:

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        //интернет доступен
    }
```

Comment: Из-за таких советчиков я вынужден пересобирать приложения, вырезая из них getActiveNetworkInfo(), или просто отказываясь от них в пользу других, не "завирусованных". И ведь не отличишь, нужна ли приложению сеть для работы заявленной части, или для слежки и слива приватной информации, коей информация о местоположении и является.

Comment: @bukkojot , Что вы этим хотите сказать? Данное приложение я хочу использовать для себя. не для  распространения. Вы про это?

Comment: Речь не про вас, а про советчика лазить в интернет тогда, когда это не требуется.

Comment: @bukkojot , в данном ответе не было ни слова о том, когда лазить в интернет, а когда нет. Тут лишь приведён способ проверки состояния соединения.